# Why is the data of an ajax request empty using angularjs?

Tags: php, json

I'm testing angularjs' simple ajax request and it seems to be not working. The request is made, and I'm getting 200, but the data is not passing.

```
$http({
        url: "myphp.php",
        method: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {"foo":"bar"}
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(data);
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.status = status;
});

<?php

echo var_dump($_GET);

?>
```

Same result both with get and post. If I'm trying to access $_GET['foo'] for instance, I'm getting an undefined index exception.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the return from PHP? What is the body of the response?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/SEezJCY7ngBWy6W0IuJW If that's not satisfying, please explain, if you can, how can I get more info using php5.4's built in http server @CaioToOn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your data is sent to your PHP in a JSON encoded body (`{dataType: "json", data: {"foo": "bar"}}`). Not as GET/POST parameters.

As you're passing the data in body and your PHP is trying to retrieve in $_GET, you are getting `undefined index`.

Not sure what the right way in PHP, but it's should be something like this:

```php
$requestBody = file_get_contents('php://input');
$requestBody = json_decode($requestBody);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because PHP does not accept JSON `'application/json'` you need to update your headers and parameters from angular appropriately.

**First**, Parameterize your data:

```
data: $.param({ "foo": $scope.fooValue })
```

**Then**, add the following to your `$http`

```
 headers: {
     'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
 },
```

*If all of your requests are going to PHP the parameters can be set globaly in the configuration as follows:*

```
myApp.config(function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8';
});
```